# Getting all objects from array with specific property in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

If i have this schema

```
food = {
    name : String,
    favouriteFoods : []
}
```

and each favoritefood element is an object like so

```
var favoritefood = new Object;
favoritefood.cuisine = 'indian';
favoritefood.flavor = 'spicy';
```

is it possible to query mongoose to get all favoritefood objects have their flavor attribute set to 'spicy'?

Comment: Try using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an `aggregate` operation to get all the spicy favouirite foods grouped by name.

- `Match` all the food items, having at least one spicy favorite food.
- `Unwind` the favorite food array.
- `Match` all the unwinded favorite foods which are spicy.
- `Group` by the food name.
- `Project` them.

The Code:

```
Food.aggregate([
{$match:{"favouriteFoods.flavor":"spicy"}},
{$unwind:"$favouriteFoods"},
{$match:{"favouriteFoods.flavor":"spicy"}},
{$group:{"_id":"$name","spicyFoods":{$push:"$favouriteFoods"}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"name":"$_id","spicyFoods":1}}
],function(err,res){
// console.log(res);
})
```